# Виртуальное разбиение корзины

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеется заказ со своей корзиной, ее необходимо разбить на "виртуальные корзины" так, чтобы во главе каждой корзины стоял основной продукт, а все неосновные были приписаны к первому (первый определяется по максимальной цене, цена у всех разная).
Пример:

```
basket;product;price;ismain
Корзина1;Товар1;50;1
Корзина1;Товар2;10;0
Корзина1;Товар3;15;1
Корзина1;Товар4;25;0
Корзина1;Товар5;35;0
Корзина1;Товар6;5;1
```

Необходимо:

```
basket;product;price;ismain
Корзина1;Товар1;50;1
Корзина1;Товар2;10;0
Корзина1;Товар4;25;0
Корзина1;Товар5;35;0
Корзина2;Товар3;15;1
Корзина3;Товар6;5;1
```

Можно ли это сделать GROUP'ами и/или UNION'ами, с достаточной производительностью или стоит смотреть в сторону PL/pgSQL?

Comment: 1) По какому признаку именно "Товар1" выбран тем основным, к которому были "приписаны" все неосновные? 2) Вообще задача решается тупой сортировкой ОТОБРАЖЕНИЯ на клиенте.

Comment: 1) По дате добавления, например. 2) Это задача для аналитики, хотелось бы сформировать view

Comment: *По дате добавления, например.* В показанных данных НЕТ даты добавления. *Это задача для аналитики, хотелось бы сформировать view* да как два пальца, но... сперва продумайте, а потом откорректируйте свой вопрос - чтобы ни одного дополнительного вопроса не требовалось и ни одной непонятки не осталось.

Comment: @Akina Вообще подходил вариант с любым первым элементом (рандомно), но если добавление этого условия улучшит вопрос то добавил.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо! Мне совет помог, если оформишь как ответ, то помечу его как решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Вообще подходил вариант с любым первым элементом (рандомно)

В CTE считаешь дополнительно

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ismain ORDER BY что-нибудь) AS rn
```

Это самое "что-нибудь" определяет, к какому основному прилепятся все дополнительные.

Потом сортируешь по выражению типа

```
CASE WHEN ismain=1 AND rn=1 THEN 0 
                            ELSE 1 END, 
CASE WHEN ismain=0 THEN 0 
                   ELSE 1 END, 
rn
```

Первый CASE сделает первой записью ту основную, которая получила первый номер.

Второй CASE после неё выведет все "дополнительные", а потом все оставшиеся "основные".

Последняя группа (`rn`) отсортирует записи в блоках дополнительных и остальных основных записей по возрастанию посчитанного номера. Возможно (с учётом того, что устраивает рандом) её вообще можно убрать.

Ну и с учётом кучи корзин - подкорректируй PARTITION и финальный ORDER BY.